# How to specify Lucene.net boolean AND, OR , not operator from normal and, or and not variables?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

In my project i was implementing a full text index search using Lucence. But while doing this i was stuck up with a logic of differentiating Lucene boolean operators from Normal and, or , not words.

Suppose for example if we are searching for **"I want a pen and pencil"** , but by default Lucene.net searching Lucene OR operation. so it will search like **"I OR want OR a OR pen OR pencil"** not like what i would like to have like **"I OR want OR a OR pen OR and OR pencil"**. So how come we differentiate a normal and, or, not from Lucene operators?

For this I have done a helper method which looks like

```
/// <summary>
    /// Method to get search predicates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchTerm">Search term</param>
    /// <returns>List of predicates</returns>
    public static IList<string> GetPredicates(string searchTerm)
    {
        //// Remove unwanted characters
        //searchTerm = Regex.Replace(searchTerm, "[<(.|\n)*?!'`>]", string.Empty);
        string exactSearchTerm = string.Empty,
               keywordOrSearchTerm = string.Empty, 
               andSearchTerm = string.Empty, 
               notSearchTerm = string.Empty,
               searchTermWithOutKeywords = string.Empty;
        //// Exact search tern
        exactSearchTerm = "\"" + searchTerm.Trim() + "\"";
        //// Search term without keywords
        searchTermWithOutKeywords = Regex.Replace(
            searchTerm, " and not | and | or ", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //// Splioted keywords
        string[] splittedKeywords = searchTermWithOutKeywords.Trim().Split(
            new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //// Or search term
        keywordOrSearchTerm = string.Join(" OR ", splittedKeywords);
        //// And search term
        andSearchTerm = string.Join(" AND ", splittedKeywords);
        //// not search term
        int index = 0;
        List<string> searchTerms = (from term in Regex.Split(
                                        searchTerm, " and not ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                                        where index++ != 0
                                        select term).ToList();
        searchTerms = (from term in searchTerms
               select Regex.IsMatch(term, " and | or ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ?
               Regex.Split(term, " and | or ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).FirstOrDefault() : 
               term).ToList();
        notSearchTerm = searchTerms.Count > 0 ? string.Join(" , ", searchTerms) : "\"\"";
        return new List<string> { exactSearchTerm, andSearchTerm, keywordOrSearchTerm, notSearchTerm };
    }
```

but it will return four results. so i have to loop through my index for 4 times , but it seems to be very hectic one. so can anybody give a hand to resolve this one in a single loop?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Matt Warren suggested, lucene has what are called "stop words" that usually add little value to the quality of search but make the index HUGE and bloated.  StopWords like "a, and, or, the, an" are usually automatically filtered out of your text as it is indexed, and then filtered out of your query when it is parsed.  The [StopFilter](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html&ei=N-keTtiwL4W8sQOV4LVO&usg=AFQjCNFfvKQP2uKCqrn_1PHUAGa3oSXk3Q) is resposible for this behavior in both cases, but you can pick an analyzer that does not use the StopFilter.

The other issue is in query parsing.  If I remember correctly, the lucene query parser will only treat capitalized `OR` `AND` and `NOT` as keywords, so if the user types in all capital letters, you'll need to replace them with lower-case so it is not treated as the operators.  Here's some Regex.Replace code for that:

```
string queryString = "the red pencil and blue pencil are both not green or brown";
queryString = 
   Regex.Replace (
       queryString, 
       @"\b(?:OR|AND|NOT)\b", 
       m => m.Value.ToLowerInvariant ());
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in StandardAnalyzer will strip out common words for you, see [this article](http://www.aaron-powell.com/lucene-analyzer) for an explanation.